# Im trying to add a child in as3 but it does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, object, addchild

What am I doing wrong

```
SpawnTeams();
var Redone:RedTeam = new RedTeam();
function SpawnTeams():void{
    addChild(Redone);
}
```

I get this error:

`Type error 2007`

Comment: Is there any additional information in the error, or just the error code?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling SpawnTeam before you have declared Redone. Switch round the lines 'var Redone:RedTeam...' with 'SpawnTeams();'

```
var Redone:RedTeam = new RedTeam();

SpawnTeams(); //This line is moved

function SpawnTeams():void{
    addChild(Redone);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, error 2007 is telling you have an event listener with no arguments (event listeners should look something like `function foo(e:Event):void {`)

Comment: Sorry about my comment about not showing any listeners Atriace (which I've just removed), I thought you were the original poster. Just realised you're not!

Comment: lol, no worries. You have a correct answer, and I was just adding an addendum explaining his `Type Error`.